# Using an array to get string values in mySQL

Tags: mysql, arrays, select

I need to get all rows that contains the values passed by parameter, in an array.

If I have a single value (like "loren" OR "ipsum") in the column, I just can use:

```
SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE FIND_IN_SET (Column, 'loren, ipsum') > 0
```

and everything will work.

But, if my column contains something like "Loren Ipsum Dolor", the `FIND_IN_SET` don't work. How can I retrieve values considering all words in the column?

Comment: `FIND_IN_SET()` indicates a denormalised data structure, which is often a very poor design decision.  Take advantage of your RDBMS's relational capabilities and [normalise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) your schema!

Comment: Ok, but if my Table is a blog post and the array passed by parameter is a search from an user?

So I need to search two (or more) words within the entire post. I think it's not a schema problem.
In this case, has another option, instead of FIND_IN_SET, in MySQL?

Comment: If you had a normalised schema, you could group your table of keywords by blog post and then filter the groups for only those which contain all of the search terms.